How do I rename duplicate variables in a list of data.frames?
I want to rename several duplicated variable names, 'NA.', of data tables contained in a list using map2 so that the column names are not duplicated. This question has been asked (Failure to rename duplicate column names with dplyr rename() and rename_with()), but only for one data frame using the dplyr package. Below is a toy example.
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
a <-  data.table(All = rep(c('a', c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(2:4))))

b <-  data.table(All = rep(c('a', c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(2:4))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(3:5))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(4:6))))
c <- list(a,b)
c
#> [[1]]
#>    All NA. NA.
#> 1:   a  NA  NA
#> 2:   1   1   2
#> 3:   2   2   3
#> 4:   3   3   4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    All NA. NA. NA. NA.
#> 1:   a  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2:   1   1   2   3   4
#> 3:   2   2   3   4   5
#> 4:   3   3   4   5   6

I am able to figure out how to make unique the variable names for one data.table using the following code.
d <- make.unique(dput(names(a)))
#> c("All", "NA.", "NA.")
d
#> [1] "All"   "NA."   "NA..1"
names(a) <- d
names(a)
#> [1] "All"   "NA."   "NA..1"

However, when I try to apply a similar logic using map2 from the purrr package, I get the an error.
map(c, ~names(.x) %>% dput %>% make.unique()) -> e
#> c("All", "NA.", "NA.")
#> c("All", "NA.", "NA.", "NA.", "NA.")
e
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "All"   "NA."   "NA..1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "All"   "NA."   "NA..1" "NA..2" "NA..3"
map2(c, e, ~.y ->> names(.x))
#> Error in names(.x) <<- ~.y: object '.x' not found

I have tried using setnames from data.table, but the I get an error because the function does not like working with data tables that have duplicate column names. I am open to using rename_with with map, but the nature of this project means I have to first make the variable names non unique (they can be absolutely meaningless) before I adjust the names to something more meaningful. For now, I am fine with a variable name like 'NA..1'.
What I am trying to figure out is how to remove the duplicity of the variable names, since all subsequent operations involving the data requires variable names to be unique. Ideas?

map(c_dflist, \(x) setnames(x, make.unique(names(x))))

or w/o the purrr dependency
lapply(c_dflist, \(x) setnames(x, make.unique(names(x))))

Where
a <-  data.table(All = rep(c('a', c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(2:4))))
b <-  data.table(All = rep(c('a', c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(1:3))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(2:4))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(3:5))),
                 NA. = rep(c(NA, c(4:6))))
c_dflist <- list(a,b)


Excellent- thank you so much! Why does adding the '` and embracing x with '( )' work? Is this in data.table/purrr documentation?

\(x) is  shorthand for function(x), a relatively recent addition to R) I think that kind of makes purrr's ~ obsolete.
